# PHPStorm / Webstorm, how to open a file with the associated program

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I am a new user of Webstorm/PHPStorm. Before this IDE, I used Netbeans.
To open a .xds file, that is a kind of text file that you can open it just like a .js file
and edit it in the editor. 
In Netbeans you have to option to choose: **open in system**. Now the associated program gets started and opens it with the selected file.

Is there a alternative way to do this in Webstorm/Phpstorm? For now I just rightclick and choose
for the option: Show in Explorer. And then doubleclick the file .xds.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21):

Use **Files opened in associated applications** in `File` | `Settings` | `File Types`:

[image: associated]

Comment: Thanks! The only drawback of this, is that the file now always opens with the associated program. But the file itself is also a text file like xml that you can edit. You also want to edit this in PHPStorm/Webstorm IDE.

Comment: You can do that with the external tool bound to a keyboard shortcut like suggested by @LazyOne.

Comment: This allowed me to remove a wrongly added file, I spent quite some time to find it. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK there is no such action available in current versions.

Two options:

1. Assign such extension / pattern to **File opened in associated applications** in `Settings | Editor | File Types`. **Cons:** you will not be able to open such file in IDE itself.
2. Create custom **External Tool** entry (`Settings | Tools | External Tools`) that will launch such file with default application in your OS. For Windows it can be:

`Program: cmd.exe`
`Parameters: /C start "$FilePath$"`