# In WebStorm, change file opening behavior

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I, a long time ago, set WebStorm to open `.md` files in an other application every time I would double click on the file.

But now, I would like to open my `markdown` files directly in WebStorm.

Where do I manage file opening behavior in `WebStorm` ?

Comment: are you using terminal?

Comment: No, I am not using the terminal. I just want to open my `README.md` in webstorm when I double click on it within WebStorm. I recall modifying file opening setting in webstorm for markdown a long time ago but I cant find it anywhere in the ide preferences anymore

Comment: Oh ok, I found it. that is the answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879589/phpstorm-webstorm-how-to-open-a-file-with-the-associated-program